# Convergence of an oscillatory integral to real number

Tags: fourier-transform, integration, mathematics, complex-numbers, calculus

I have a physical model, where the long-time behavior of the system can be described by
$$C(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\mathrm{d}k\,\mathrm{e}^{-t\omega(k)}$$
with $\omega(k)\geq0$ and $\omega(t)\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. For the model I basically assumed that the function in the exponent is real because of physical reasons, but there are some aspects of the system that lead to $C(t)$ saturating in special cases. I then was wondering if it is possible to have an imaginary part $\sigma(k)$, such that
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}C(t)=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\mathrm{d}k\,\mathrm{e}^{-t(\omega(k)+\mathrm{i}\sigma(k))}=\text{const.}>0$$
and that I was erroneously disregarding this part. This integral seems to fit what is called an oscillatory integral, but it seems they almost always converge to zero (for example, by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma). Are there choices for $\sigma$ such that I get the integral to not vanish in the limit $t\to\infty$?

Edit: To make things easier for a beginning, we can assume $\omega$ to be given by $\omega(k)=k^4$. Maybe there is a concrete example for this case.

Comment: you need to provide more detailed structure of $\omega(k)$.

Comment: $\omega$ is an even polynomial (strictly speaking it is a function of the form $\lvert f\bigl(\sin(k),\cos(k)\bigr)\rvert^2$ but you can expand it around the slowest decaying nodes), for simplicity you can assume it is given by $\omega(k)=k^4$

Comment: Even if there is an imaginary part (for some physical model reasons), it will be killed by the evanescent of real part $e^{- \alpha t + i \beta t}$. It wont lead to a saturation behavior of $C(t)$.

Comment: oh well, I already imagined this would be the case. Otherwise would have been nice, though, because you could interpret the imaginary part as some sort of "dissipative" contribution, which would have been a nice insight

Comment: Note that $$ 0 \leq \left| \int_a^b \mathrm{d}k e^{-t (\omega(k)+ i \sigma(k)}  \right| \leq \int_a^b \mathrm{d}k  \left| e^{-t (\omega(k)+ i \sigma(k)} \right| = \int_a^b \mathrm{d}k  e^{-t \omega(k)}$$ and so if $\lim_{t \to \infty} C(t) = 0$ without the imaginary part in the exponent it will also vanish in the limit where $\sigma(k) \neq 0$, by the squeeze theorem.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert you're right, I should have seen this. Thanks!